# RApache config problem

Tags: configuration, r, rapache

My sysadmin installed [RApache](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/index.html) for me on our 64 bit Solaris box.  I can access the [RApacheInfo](http://ri.imb.nrc.ca/zbroom/test/) page here, indicating that the module was successfully installed.  There is the following entry in the httpd.conf:

```
<Directory /websites/zbroom>
  SetHandler r-script
  RHandler brew::brew
</Directory>
```

which should require all files in the directory to be parsed through the brew function of the [brew](http://www.rforge.net/brew/) package.  As can be seen on my [test page](http://ri.imb.nrc.ca/zbroom/Rtest), the R code is ignored.  There are no errors thrown (nothing in the Apache logs).

This is the test code:

```
<html><head><title>R test</title></head>
<body>
<p>here is some normal text</p>

<%=rnorm(100) %>
<% print(rnorm(100)) %>

<p>Between this text and the first text there should be some R output.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to change so that the R code will be evaluated and printed?

Comment: AFAIK RApache has its own mailing list, you probably want to check there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Dirk's advice I posted at the google [RApache group](http://groups.google.ca/group/rapache/browse_thread/thread/85369c8f55743c47?hl=en#). It appears the issue was not bad config, but that Apache needed a restart for things to take effect. Sigh, well at least the fix was easy.